# Typescript types to include one extra property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a typeScript interface like below -

```js
interface MovieStar {
  birth: ActorAddress;
  actorWiki: ActorDescription | ActorByMovie;
}

interface ActorAddress {
  city: string;
  state: string;
  country: string
}

interface ActorDescription {
  name: string;
  hobby: string;
}

interface ActorByMovie extends ActorDescription {
  movieName: string;
}
```

When I am trying to use the interface `movieStar` and access `actorWiki`, I am getting only common properties of `ActorDescription` and `ActorByMovie` and I am not able to access movieName.

My requirement: I am using React with TypeScript and I have assigned `movieStar` as a type for the data fetched from an API.

Now, I have another API the response of which is similar in structure, but has one extra property called `movieName` which I am not able to access.

Am I doing something wrong here or shall I structure my interface in some other way? I came across the concept of Discriminated Unions but I think it is useful when we want both scenarios in one component (discriminated based on type). Here, I want the interface with extra properties in a separate component itself.

Comment: Should the type of `actorWiki` be:  `actorWiki: ActorDescription | ActorByMovie;` ?

Comment: @Harrison In short, no. This is what I tried to do. I have mentioned the requirement below the code under "My requirement" section

Comment: @MohitChauhan I think wanted to point out a typo. Your interfaces are (correctly) named with a Capital but in the union you try to use them using lowercase names which is invalid code.

Comment: @Behemoth That was my bad. Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it seems like you're encountering an issue due to the union type `actorDescription | actorByMovie` within your `MovieStar` interface. TypeScript will only allow you to access properties that are common to all types in the union when you try to access `actorWiki`. This is why you're unable to access `movieName` directly, as it's not a property on `ActorDescription`.

Even though you mentioned that you might not need Discriminated Unions since you're handling different scenarios in separate components, they could still offer a solution to your problem. The key here is to provide a way for TypeScript to differentiate between the two types at runtime, which can then be used to safely access properties specific to one type.

To achieve this, you can introduce a discriminant property (commonly a type property) to your interfaces. Here's how you can adjust your interfaces to use Discriminated Unions effectively:

```
interface ActorAddress {
  city: string;
  state: string;
  country: string;
}

// Add a type property to both ActorDescription and ActorByMovie
interface ActorDescription {
  type: 'actorDescription';
  name: string;
  hobby: string;
}

interface ActorByMovie extends ActorDescription {
  type: 'actorByMovie'; // Override the type property to differentiate
  movieName: string;
}

// Now, MovieStar can utilize the discriminated union for actorWiki
interface MovieStar {
  birth: ActorAddress;
  actorWiki: ActorDescription | ActorByMovie;
}
```

With this setup, you can use a type guard to check the type property and TypeScript will then allow you to access properties specific to that type:

```
function displayActorWiki(actorWiki: ActorDescription | ActorByMovie) {
  if (actorWiki.type === 'actorByMovie') {
    // TypeScript knows actorWiki is ActorByMovie here, so you can access movieName
    console.log(actorWiki.movieName);
  } else {
    // actorWiki is ActorDescription here
    console.log(actorWiki.name);
  }
}
```

This way, you can use the same `MovieStar` interface but still differentiate between the cases when you have additional properties to access. This approach keeps your types flexible and allows you to use them in different components as needed, while still maintaining type safety.

Comment: That was a wonderful explanation. I have just one question. What if I pass `MovieStar` as a prop, and if I do `movieStart.actorWiki`. How will I discriminate types in this case? Like let's say I want properties in `ActorByMovie` in this case

Comment: with `movieStar: MovieStar` as the prop you would check for `if (movieStar.actorWiki.type === 'actorByMovie')` to access `movieStar.actorWiki.movieName`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case you might be able to simply [*narrow*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) `MovieStar["actorWiki"]` with the `in`-operator.

```
if("movieName" in movieStar.actorWiki) {
    movieStar.actorWiki.movieName;
    //                  ^? (property) ActorByMovie.movieName: string
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsBuwIGUxxTIDeAUMsgEbBRgAWAXMgIIJjpTMAmXUEAzvwDc5ZInZQA6sADWwJqwkARAQijAADmGDoQyAD4s2HAEIBPDNggiAvqVKhIsRCkUduvAfxKiEwMGZM-GDqIADmIhTBcJBBIaARvugAruBQgcjBoWGkdg7g0PBIRsqq6lo6emQUIHAAthBx2ZHIdOiUlBlZCbb2joUuJaYWWDjIEAAekCBc3m5QKvxqmtq6PhR1oxAAcvWNmfHhvaRcEAgANoQoCLrByJtW+IRMljhPUCIPbwRQAHTiHGkchEDhgAAoAERfHZ7CHIUD3Lbvf7GKSyYAASnWFERjx+KIkQOAv2huwaLQoAHpKTjaXT6QA9AD8uVIQA)

Another approach I find reasonable based on your problem description is to declare `movieName` as [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) inside `ActorDescription`. That way you can save yourself an interface. `movieName` will be `string | undefined` but you can narrow it to `string` as explained above.

```
interface MovieStar {
  birth: ActorAddress;
  actorWiki: ActorDescription
}

interface ActorAddress {
  city: string;
  state: string;
  country: string
}

interface ActorDescription {
  name: string;
  hobby: string;
  movieName?: string;
}

declare const movieStar: MovieStar;
movieStar.actorWiki.movieName;
//                  ^? (property) ActorDescription.movieName?: string | undefined
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsBuwIGUxxTIDeAUMsgEbBRgAWAXMgIIJjpTMAmXUEAzvwDc5ZInZQA6sADWwJqwkARAQijAADmGDoQpAL6lSoSLEQpFHbrwH8SohMDABPJvzDqQAcxEV3cSDcPUB8HdABXcChXZHdPLwMjE2h4JBY2DhV+NU1tXXsKEDgAWwgg+N9kOnRKShi4kMrirBwAORKIAH5yxsTSLggEABtCFARdd2Rm7DwCKCYMGfxCEWmcZagAOnEOaTlNtYh20pEAelOKS6vrq4A9TtIgA)

Comment: I thought about the second solution. But I didn't want to use `optional chaining`. Also, the solution that you have given to narrow down to the `string`, how can it be used in React when passing `MovieStar` as a prop, as the data is coming from an API and I am not assigning it to any object

Comment: Could you please edit your question and include the relevant code for that? Hard to tell what the problem is without seeing how you handle it in your components.